# How to get relative path to folder containing a .m file

Tags: matlab

I write code where I load a lot of project data. I want to keep my pathnames in the code relative to some location of this project on the disk, i.e. not having it configured or hard-coded.

Is there function in matlab to do some like this?

In python I would write:

```
ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better recipe to organize your code is to have a function like this:

```
function [ path ] = get_path()
     path = [regexprep(mfilename('fullpath'), ['\' filesep '[\w\.]*$'],'') filesep];
end
```

You drop it inside `+foo/get_path.m` file and than call something like `foo.get_path()` that returns the path to `+foo` folder.

Comment: How is this better than Suever’s answer? Seems more complicated without adding anything useful.

Comment: Nothing against Suever direct approach or solution. But what about cross-platform pathnames (for Mac/Linux/Windows) and modules? If your point is that modular code is useless, then I would rather not have this discussion. I find that modules in matlab do have value, unfortunately they are less known. The question asked above is about learning absolute pathname WITHOUT storing absolute pathnames inside project configuration files or code.. 
I find the usage of  config.load_project_path() readable and comprehensive, but fileparts and mfilename less so.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to combine [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html?refresh=true) with [`mfilename('fullpath')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html). (All examples assume the executing m-file containing these statements lives in `/home/suever/code/stackoverflow.m`)

```
mfiledir = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));

    /home/suever/code
```

Then you can use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to construct any paths you need from that. Now if you have a file (`data.mat`) stored in the same directory:

```
filename = fullfile(mfiledir, 'data.mat');

    /home/suever/code/data.mat
```

Of if the file is actually in the parent directory.

```
filename = fullfile(mfiledir, '..', 'data.mat');

    /home/suever/data.mat
```

If you want *just* the parent directory that an m-file is in, you can apply `fileparts` twice and only keep the second output.

```
[~, reldir] = fileparts(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')));

    code
```

I would recommend the use of full paths in the first examples as those are completely independent of the user's current working directory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The only but is I would not `recommend the use of absolute paths` if you plan to run your code on another computer. I.e. like unless you code for OS kernel - never use absolute hardcoded path names in any user programs.

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich I'm confused. There are no hard-coded paths anywhere here. The paths are computed on the fly based on the m-file location. The *absolute* I'm talking about is using the first option I posted as opposed to the last option I posted.

Comment: Right, after careful checking - you actually say absolute  pathnames instead of **hardcoded absolute pathnames** (what I misread). My bad.

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich I have updated the post to call them "full paths" so as to not confuse. Thanks for pointing that out